# Citrix Remote Session Video/Audio Delay Issues

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, citrix

I am experiencing issues with the Video and Audio matching up for Terminal Desktops running on our Citrix Servers. We are running Citrix Xenapp 6.

Users open chrome and open videos, the video loads, but it appears that the Audio is not sync'd up and lags behind the actual picture of the video.

Is there anything in Citrix that I can be using to troubleshoot the issue?

Are there known fixes for this Video/Audio Sync issue?

I currently have little background with citrix, and guidance or information is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: tried unchecking hardware acceleration in the browser, this didn't seem to fix the issue for the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the fact that you are talking about "users", I would argue that this is a general problem somewhere around your VM.

Although this is a far fetch, try following [this article](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX104912).

Additionally, [that](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX118836) might help you more.

Furthermore, I would advise to first try the following, which in my personal experience helped ruling out a bad connection as the reason for async:

Open your Citrix Studio, head to Policies, create a new policy, head to Client Devices -> Resources -> Audio -> Sound Quality. Set that policy to Low or Medium, apply it to all devices. AFAIK you could also apply it to AD-Groups, if this helps you limiting policies (which I advice you, in general I avoid policies because they slow the startup down, but sometimes there is no way around).

Those steps are also described in the second article.

Now if this all did not help, try another browser. Chromium Edge works great btw., if you are already using Server2016 or 2019, it is less of a bi*ch for optimizing in Citrix, because Chrome can sometimes cause random errors.

Last but not least, and I heavily doubt this is the cause of your problem, but if the video disrupts the connection shortly, the audio can desync. [This article](https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-virtual-apps-desktops/policies/reference/ica-policy-settings/auto-client-reconnect-policy-settings.html) describes additional policies for troubleshooting/limiting audio desync from connection disruptions.

I hope I could help you, and if not I am sorry. Sadly (or gladly) we only ever had to fight with audio problems due to bad connections which were solved via the first step I described of limiting the quality.